# Can I get relics back from AI players?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I like to play with a computer ally so I can trade for gold, but he takes all the relics. I know it's possible to wall them, but is there a way to get the relic back after the AI has taken it?

It would be nice anyway to have some commands to control your ally a bit.

I use the addon Forgotten Empires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually did in those cases was using siege onagers and the attack in an area command to destroy their monastery (note that I had enforced teams so this aggression went unnoticed). If your civilization doesn't have those, I believe other siege weapons can do it.

Comment: I don't own AoE2, but do you think you could attack the ground *next to* the monastery, so it gets destroyed by the splash damage instead? That way you wouldn't have to worry about your diplomatic relationship, right?

Comment: @Nolonar Even collateral damage will cause AI allies to break ties.

Comment: I don't remember well the AI "friendliness", but you can always switch to enemy and convert/destroy before switching back to ally ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to get him to give it to you.

You could take a unit like a Trebuchet or Mangonel and use the "Attack Ground" command though. Tell them to attack the ground on a Monastery and you should be able to damage it enough to take the relics yourself if your Monks are quick enough.

Answer (score 1):

The Conquerors did add some commands to control your ally, but I don't think any pertained to relics... Clicking the chat button in the upper right, then clicking "Commands" in the lower left of the popup brings up the list of valid commands.

[image]